# How to stop a disabled device from installing the new version of the beta version of the app?

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have disabled a device in the devices list in the provisioning portal, now when i archive the app and put it for wireless ad-hoc distribution I can still download the app on the disabled device. How can i stop the disabled device from downloading the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you disable a certain device you get a message that you will invalidate all existing provisioning profiles where that device was selected.

You need to go the provisioning profile section and edit all of them where the status is invalid. Review the devices and regenerate the profile. Afterwards you can download them and import them into XCode by using the Organizer.

Now when you archive your application and distribute it with the newly updated provisioning profile it should no longer work on the disabled device.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this solves my confusion and answers my question :)